Magisk Root Detection for Flutter or Android Application
Is their any way to detect whether the device is rooted using Magisk Root (https://github.com/topjohnwu/Magisk/releases/tag/v27.0) with the combinations of other Apps and Modules to Hide whether the Android device is rooted.
Apps like https://github.com/Dr-TSNG/Hide-My-Applist/releases/tag/V3.2 and
Modules like

https://github.com/LSPosed/LSPosed/releases/tag/v1.9.2
https://github.com/kdrag0n/safetynet-fix/releases
https://github.com/LSPosed/LSPosed.github.io/releases

There are few more Modules and library are present which helps Magisk Root Hide
Magisk Root App Download dynamic Stub APK with dynamic package name, SHA key signature, icon, app name, bypass google play integrity and safetynet.
I have tried both for Flutter and Native Android like
Flutter Plugins :
https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_jailbreak_detection
https://pub.dev/packages/freerasp by Talsec
and for Android tried to find whether

SU Directory / file / dangerous Apk Exists
isPathExist("su")
isHaveReadWritePermission - for SU
isHaveRootManagementApps - whether there packages installed or exists
isHaveDangerousProperties
isHaveRootHideApps
DebuggerDetector

most of the other open source solutions has been bypassed my magisk
What to know any other path i can follow or apply to detect magisk root hide.
Thanks in advance

Try a combination of checks including known tampered paths, etc (already covered by others in relevant articles). For your case as a last resort, call a native function in case previous checks  they can be hooked and thus bypassed.
Check this repo for it's use of native library.
It's still working as of today for Magisk 24+

That is not helping, that repo has been archived and with other combinations that can also be bypassed.

It's a game of cat and mouse, and always will be.

You can try the most common and recent patterns, but still always there will be a small door for someone if that's your concern.
